# SerialSearch with Cursors

Tags: pybliometrics

I am trying to use SerialSearch to identify about 800 titles with a single keyword. When I run:

```
serialSearch = SerialSearch(query={"title": "myKeyword"})
```

it gives me the first 200. I would like to get the remaining 600. I saw there is a start parameter that appears to be deprecated in favor of a cursor but I can't find any details on how to implement it. Is there a reference example for this?

Answer (score 1):

With the current development version you can pass `start=200` to the class, to get entries ranging from 200 to 399.

1. Install via

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pybliometrics-dev/pybliometrics
```

3. Then use

```
serialSearch = SerialSearch(query={"subject": "ECON"}, start=200, refresh=True)
```

The `refresh=True` bit is important, otherwise pybliometrics will use the old information.

Eventually Scopus implements pagination with cursors akin to the Scopus Search API, which would solve this problem.